# PureConfig: I cannot read a reference.conf in a sbt Plugin

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-plugin, pureconfig

I created a *sbt Plugin*, that reads its configuration from a `reference.conf`.

The test in the `Plugin` works (can read the `reference.conf).

Wenn I publish the Plugin, there is the `reference.conf` in the Root of the Jar.

However when running the SBT Task that should use this `reference.conf` it does not get it.

I use:

```
ConfigSource.default.loadOrThrow[TemplateConfig]
```

Reloading the *SBT Console* did not help.

Is this a restriction of SBT Plugins or do I miss something?